# What was preventing this question from getting migrated?

Tags: bug, migration

Earlier [slhck](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) tried to migrate [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/546758/web-sniffer-http-viewer) to WebApps but it simply.. failed

[image]

I tried migrating it, and it [just got closed & locked](https://superuser.com/posts/546758/revisions). I see now, the question's been automatically migrated to WebApps - so what was preventing it from getting migrated earlier, twice?

Comment: This has happened on CSTheory as well this morning: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/migration-problem

Comment: Maybe it had pending edit? Not enough rep on that site so can't check the suggested edits history myself.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd there was no pending edit.

Comment: User post-banned on receiving site?

Comment: @AlEverett no, no posts on the site.Plus we get a message if that's the case

Comment: I was thinking it might have been because the user was post banned on the source site? So you can't migrate anything away either. But I wouldn't see a good reason to implement such a thing.

Comment: I remember an incident from quite some time ago which showed a similar behavior, turned out to be race condition which resulted in the question being closed & locked but not migrated. Could be that the situation cleared itself here, though.